# jupyter notebook matplotlib figureframe changes size unexpectedly

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to have a jupyter notebook shows a progression of plots in a for loop. The code works, but for some reason the size of the figure changes after the for loop is done. Here's a set of minimal code to illustrate this (in jupyter notebook)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


%matplotlib notebook

for i in range(10):
    plt.gca().scatter(np.random.rand(10),
                      np.random.rand(10))
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.gcf().canvas.flush_events()
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

A gif illustrating the issue is attached. This problem has been driving me crazy and changing margins or using tight_layouts() do not help. It seems to be related to how FigureFrame object is rendered. [image: gif]Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try defining the figure size? I tried your code and works fine for me. You can try using `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))` outside for loop

Comment: Yes, I did, figsize still leaves a lot of empty spaces. I forgot to mention that the error only occurs after running it twice.

Comment: i can't replicate the problem. Can you add to the question OS, python, jupyter  and matpltlib version?

Comment: thx for investigating the problem, here are my versions:
OSX 10.13.6
python 3.7
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
matplotlib==3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the advantage of `matplotlib.animation` into play. It'll make sure the figure is completely drawn before starting the animation.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def animate(i):
    plt.gca().scatter(np.random.rand(10),
                      np.random.rand(10))

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=10, interval=500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Indeed I'm now looking at ways to use FuncAnimation... I have a rather complicated for loop involving other custom objects and conditional statements that are not so easily incorporated into FuncAnimation but a workaround may be possible after some work.